# git "Host key verification failed" despite following instructions 100%

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh

I get the `Host key verification failed.` error despite following [GitHub's Tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) on how to create and add a new SSH key to the letter. This is likely a local problem since I get the same error for my university git, which uses GitHub Enterprise.

I will use GitHub as an example, but the process is the same:

```
user@hostname:~$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "user@redacted.com"
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
The key fingerprint is:
[redacted] user@redacted.com
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
|    o.           |
| + +  .  .       |
|o O o Q.+        |
|.* B +.o .       |
|o & =.o X        |
| * E o..         |
|  B X.+          |
| o =o=           |
|  ++oo.          |
+----[SHA256]-----+
user@hostname:~$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 5220
user@hostname:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 (user@redacted.com)
```

Then I add the public key to my GitHub account. First I use `xclip` to copy the contents of the public key file:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo apt-get install xclip
[sudo] password for user: 
[install log for xclip. long and boring]
user@hostname:~$ xclip -selection clipboard < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

Go to github.com > Click icon in upper right corner > Settings > SSH and GPG keys > new SSH key > Paste contents and give it a name > Add SSH Key

And yet...

```
user@hostname:~$ ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? 
Host key verification failed.
```

Like I said, same problem occurs with my university git. What's the problem here?

FYI this is a brand new install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55422866/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was with this option:

```
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Selecting `yes` verified my host key. No idea why, if anyone could shed some light on it in the comments it would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not verifying your host key, you're verifying github.com's key.  This is to prevent a machine from impersonating github.